# Может ли в определенных случаях интерфейс содержать тело метода в языке java

Tags: java

Может ли в определенных случаях интерфейс содержать тело метода в языке java?

Answer (score 3):

Да. Начиная с Java 8, используя ключевое слово `default`, это вполне осуществимо.

```
interface Formula {    
    default double sqrt(int a) {
        return Math.sqrt(a);
    }
}
```

---

```
void add(X element);

default void addAll(Collection<X> elements) {
    elements.forEach(this::add);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,Алексей!